# Spatialite: Convert polygon to multi-polygons based on common field

Tags: spatialite

I have a list of polygons which should be multipolygons:

```
PK_UID | PolygonID | Geometry
------------------------------
1      | 1         | polygon
2      | 2         | polygon
3      | 1         | polygon
```

How do I convert them to multipolygons in Spatialite based on the common field (PolygonID)? (e.g So they look like this):

```
PK_UID | PolygonID | Geometry
-----------------------------------
1      | 1         | multi-polygon
2      | 2         | polygon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT PolygonID, Collect(Geometry) 
FROM polygons
GROUP BY PolygonID
```

If you want this as a new MULTIPOLYGON layer, then first create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE multipolys (PolygonID integer);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('multipolys','Geometry',<SRID>,'MULTIPOLYGON',2);
```

Now do an INSERT from the above SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO multipolys (PolygonID, geometry)
SELECT PolygonID, Collect(Geometry) 
FROM polygons
GROUP BY PolygonID
```